# Simple ssl termination with multiple certificates. Nginx/haproxy or other?

Tags: ssl, nginx, haproxy

Currently I have multiple vhosts in many configuration files with dedicated certificates.

My goal is to reach simple server configuration which support multiple certificates in one simple config (I want merge multiple vhosts files into one). I've tried with nginx something like:

```
server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl.d/*/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl.d/*/privkey.pem;

    #
    # detailed ssl config
    #
    location / {

        proxy_pass http://other_location:80;
        #
        # detailed proxy config
        #
    }
}
```

but it returns:

```
nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/nginx/ssl.d/*/cert.pem") failed
(SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or
directory:fopen('/etc/nginx/ssl.d/*/cert.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO
routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
```

I don't want configure any hostnames (maybe I wrong?).
And also I don't want rather configure paths to certificates multiple times in haproxy nor other maps.

Any idea?

Comment: There is no support for the thing you want, i.e. specifying some wildcard location where it should pick up all certificates. If you find it too time consuming to create all the configurations by hand just script it.

Answer (score 0):

With haproxy I can pass directory with certificates and it works!

```
frontend www-https
   bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution/workaround would be to generate a single multi site cert in one location using letsencrypt. You can generate simple scripts to then have the cert and key cat to one file for haproxy to use. 
That would save remembering locations for the config files.